# Magento 2: Install module from multiple repositories

Tags: magento2, composer, git, repositories

Today I've stumbled into a fairly intriguing issue.
At the moment I'm building a module for a client and possibly I'll use it for future clients. 
Now, I would like to keep the core code in a repository and the data that will change based on clients in a different one `(e.g. client specific repository)`.

**So, to summarise:**

```
- module-one <- All the core data for the module will be stored here
  - etc/
  - Model/
  - Setup/
  - composer.json
  - registration.php
 - module-one-to-inject <- Just the folder that has to be appended within module-one
  - folder-to-inject/
```

**RESULT:**

```
- module-one
  - etc/
  - Model/
  - Setup/
  - folder-to-inject/
  - composer.json
  - registration.php
```

We use satis to manage all the repositories, so the idea would be to call the core files from the generic repository and then it would require automatically the other one client-specific that will populate the **"clientspecific"** folder.

Trying my best to explain this, but i don't know if is actually clear..
Do any of you have experience with this? Never tried and my head is starting to hurt a bit!

Thanks for any help that'll come my way!